# Need some help making a php search tree

Tags: php, tree

Im making a tree to store words and an associated number array in php.  I need it to look something like this:
Words: apple, ant

```
[a] => Array
    (
        [p] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [l] => Array
                            (
                                [e] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 0
                                                [1] => 0
                                                [2] => 1
                                                [3] => 2
                                                [4] => 3
                                                [5] => 4
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [n] => Array
            (
                [t] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 0
                                [1] => 1
                                [2] => 2
                                [3] => 0
                                [4] => 0
                                [5] => 4
                             )

                    )

           )

    )
```

Of course apple and ant need to share the same [a] index.  Im close, but I cant figure out how to properly keep track of the tree index so 'apple' gets into the tree fine but 'ant' is inserted as 'nt'. Heres my code at the moment:

```
private function insertWordsIntoTree()
{
    foreach ($this->words as $word)
    {
        $characters = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $words);

        $points = $this->getPoints($word);

        $this->tree = $this->buildTree($characters, $points, $this->tree);
    }

    print_r($this->tree);
}

private function buildTree($characters, array $points, array $tree)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($characters); $i++) 
    {
        $character = $characters[$i];

        $remaining_characters = substr($characters, $i + 1);

        if (strlen($characters) === 1)
        {
            $child = [];

            $child[$character] = [$points];

            return $child;
        }
        elseif (!isset($tree[$character])) 
        {
            $tree[$character] = $this->buildTree($remaining_characters, $points, []);;

            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->buildTree($remaining_characters, $points, $tree[$character]);
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

Im pretty sure the problem is at the else statement...I dont think Im keeping track of the current tree index properly.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the content of the function getPoints()?

Comment: getPoints makes the array of numbers associated with the word.  I didnt include it in the post because it didnt seem relevant.  I've tested it thoroughly and it doesnt give any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple approach that passes the recursion off to php:

```
$tree = array();
foreach($words as $word) {
    $characters = array_reverse(str_split($word));
    $temp = array();
    foreach($characters as $index => $character) {
        if($index == 0) {
            $temp[] = getPoints($word);
        }
        $temp = array(
            $character => $temp
        );
    }
    $tree = array_merge_recursive($tree, $temp);
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this is untested.

Comment: Excellent!  Seems to work perfect.  Ill be making a testing suite for it, so I can fine tune it if I have to.  I wish I would have known about this two days ago!  Thank you.